# Angular Filter controller filter default display all objects if no category is selected

Tags: angularjs

**html**

```
ng-click="selectCategory(item)"
```

**controller**

```
 $scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
            $scope.bottomValue = newCategory;
     selectedCategory = newCategory;
      $scope.selectedPage = 1;

  }

  $scope.categoryFilterFn = function (product) {
    return selectedCategory == null ||
        product.category == selectedCategory;
   }
```

I have the category filter controller side below that's working fine and filtering the array correctly however when no category has been selected no objects are selected which is not desired

Objective : I want all values in the array to be displayed when no category is selected
e.g. note when `$scope.bottomValue` is removed from below all the objects in the array are returned.

```
$scope.edition_products = $filter('filter')( $scope.filteredItems, {approved:            true, category: $scope.bottomValue});
```

Note:  I no I can do this view side with filters but I want this  working controller side.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your condition to

`return !selectedCategory || product.category == selectedCategory;`

You might even want to add the `approved` there

`return product.approved && (!selectedCategory || product.category == selectedCategory);`

Comment: Is there a way to add the logic inline on the filter  ?

$scope.edition_products = $filter('filter')( $scope.filteredItems, {approved:            true, category: $scope.bottomValue});

Comment: @user3265817 that way it will show the items that `category` matchs `$scope.bottomValue` and if it's `falsy` it would just return the items with no category. Not sure if it's possible to do it the way you want